# Why compareTo throws NPE using a comparator who doesn't do that when user separatedly

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

I created a comparator that never throws NPE. However, when using it inside compareTo, it throws NPE. Why?

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    public static final Comparator<Person> BIRTHDATE_ASCENDING_NULLS_FIRST = Comparator
            .nullsFirst(Comparator.comparing(Person::getBirthDate, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())));

    private String name;
    private LocalDate birthDate;

    public Person() {
        super();
    }

    public Person(String name, LocalDate birthDate) {
        this();
        this.name = name;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public LocalDate getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(LocalDate birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " was born on " + (birthDate == null ? "???" : birthDate);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person other) {
        // BEGIN ADITIONAL TESTS
        if (other == null) {
            return 1;
        } else if (getBirthDate() == null ^ other.getBirthDate() == null) {
            // nulls first
            return getBirthDate() == null ? -1 : 1;
        } else if (getBirthDate() == null) {
            // both are null
            return 0;
        }
        System.out.println(this.toString() + ", " + other.toString());
        // END ADITIONAL TESTS
        return BIRTHDATE_ASCENDING_NULLS_FIRST.compare(this, other);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 1;

        result = 31 * result + (birthDate == null ? System.identityHashCode(this) : birthDate.hashCode());

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }

        if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        return Objects.equals(birthDate, ((Person) obj).getBirthDate());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
        people.add(null);
        people.add(new Person("John", null));
        people.add(new Person("Mary", LocalDate.now().minusYears(20)));
        people.add(new Person("George", LocalDate.now().minusYears(10)));

        Collections.sort(people, BIRTHDATE_ASCENDING_NULLS_FIRST);
        System.out.println(people);

        Collections.sort(people);
        System.out.println(people);

        Collections.sort(people, BIRTHDATE_ASCENDING_NULLS_FIRST.reversed());
        System.out.println(people);

        // This one throws NPE
        Collections.sort(people);
        System.out.println(people);
    }
```

When expliciting the comparator on `Collections.sort` call, sort operation doesn't use `compareTo` implementation, as expected.
When not doing this, sort operation uses the implementation of `compareTo`. Since this method calls the exact same comparator, why do I get NPE here? I mean, why the comparator doesn't handle NPE when being called from `compareTo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other calls to `sort` don't throw NPE because they call `Comparator.compare`. The call probably looks something like this:

```
theComparatorYouPassedToSort.compare(item1, item2)
```

An actual example is located at TimSort.java line 355:

```
if (c.compare(a[runHi++], a[lo]) < 0) {
```

However, the `sort` overload that doesn't take a `Comparator` (the one that throws a NPE), calls `Person.compareTo`. The call looks something like:

```
item1.compareTo(item2)
```

An actual example is located at ComparableTimSort.java line 321:

```
while (runHi < hi && ((Comparable) a[runHi]).compareTo(a[runHi - 1]) < 0)
```

Now, no matter what null handling the inner logic of `compareTo` does, the above will throw a NPE if `item1` is null. Your implementation of `compareTo` only prevents an NPE if `item2`, the parameter is null. It can handle a null parameter, but it can't change how `Person.compare` is called. If it is called on a null object, an NPE is still thrown.

Comment: I thougth compareTo was called one by one, I mean, if the array to be sorted has 4 elements, then compareTo would be called 4 times. But when debugging  ComparableTimSort.java line 321, the first method argument has the complete array. Why?

Comment: @Cássio yes it will compare them one by one, but not necessarily 4 times. It might do more comparisons depending how sorted your list is. The NPE is caused by `null.compareTo(anotherPerson)`. Why do you think the first argument shouldn’t have the complete array? What would it have instead?

Comment: I thougth it should have only the pair being compared, Then, I put some aditional logic on compareTo to ensure that both arguments are not null before calling the comparator, it should work as expected.

Comment: `compareTo` does not have two arguments. It is a method that is part of the objects to compare themselves. `john.compareTo(bob)`. It is executed directly on `john`, using `bob` as argument. So if the variable `john` does not refer to anything (`null`), the call cant be executed no matter what and will result in a NPE. There is a huge difference between `john.compareTo(bob)` and `someComparator.compare(john, bob)` in that regard. It can not even enter the method, a situation like `null.anyMethod()` already triggers the NPE, without even starting to execute `anyMethod`.

Comment: I (finally) got it. When calling "Collections.sort(people)", compareTo will be called to every person on people, which (in my example) will cause the NPE. I didn't realize that the NPE was being thrown by the call to compareTo and not by the call to the comparator inside compareTo.